# C# adding data to arrays

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, collections

I have this code:

```
public static Account[] LoadXml(string fileName) {
     Account ths = new Account();
     // load xml data
     // put data into properties/variables
     // the xml is in a structure like this:
     /*
     <accounts> 
        <account ID="test account">
         <!-- account variables here -->
        </account>
        <account ID="another test account">
         <!-- account variables here -->
        </account>
     </accounts>
     */
}
```

How would I return an array or collection that has those accounts in them?

Each `<account ID="test"></account>` is it's own `Account`.

Comment: If your `Account` class actually matches the XML document you could try just deserializing it. Otherwise use an `XmlReader` or `XDocument`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using proper xml serialization instead of writing your own. The .NET framework does handle all your problems for you, including arrays, collections or lists.

Your code should be as simple as this:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename)) {
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AccountsDocument));
    var doc = (AccountsDocument)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    return doc.Accounts;
}
```

The AccountsDocument class:

```
[XmlRoot("accounts")]
public class AccountsDocument {
    [XmlElement("account")]
    public Account[] Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

The Account class:

```
public class Account {
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("stuff")]
    public StuffType Stuff { get; set; }

    // ... and so on
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do list:

```
var result = new List<Account>
```

then add items to list:

```
result.Add(account);
```

and in the end return it:

```
return result.ToArray();
```